# Show all records if dates are null in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SET @dateFrom = ''
SET @dateTo = ''

SELECT [tNumber], [createdDate], [Total], [pfAmount] FROM [webtable]
WHERE [tNumber] LIKE '%' 
AND [createdDate] > @dateFrom+'%' 
AND [createdDate] < @dateTo+'%'
```

I am trying to get the query to show all values from the database if the dates are blank or if @dateFrom and @dateTo has a value then it should filter those specific results

Comment: Are the dates strings? Otherwise you are forcing a date to string conversion that may have unexpected results.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes the dates are in string format

Comment: You should be comparing dates not strings. You need to convert those strings to valid dates before comparison.

Comment: Dates in SQL Server don't have formats. Either you use (n)varchar columns for dates, or not.

Comment: the columns for all values are nvarchar

Comment: ... _why_ are they all strings?  That's got to be causing you all sorts of problems, just from the performance of needing to convert things...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT [tNumber], [createdDate], [Total], [pfAmount] FROM [webtable]
WHERE [tNumber] LIKE '%' 
AND (
        (       [createdDate] > @dateFrom --removed +'%'
            AND [createdDate] < @dateTo ) --close 2nd parentheses and removed +'%'
        OR      COALESCE(@dateFrom,@dateTo) IS NULL
    ) --close 1st parantheses
```

`COALESCE()` evaluates one thing after another within its parentheses until it doesn't find a NULL value.  If all values are NULL, it returns NULL.  With the way I wrote this statement, if both parameters are NULL, nothing is filtered by `[createdDate]`

UPDATE

removed `+'%'`

Comment: optionally, you can "hard-set" the parameter values:  `[createdDate] > ISNULL(@dateFrom,'1/1/1900')`.  This will force @dateFrom to include all conceivable values if it is not populated.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I can't get it to work though, is this because I have declared parameters are varchar?

Comment: I failed to remove the `+'%'` that follows `@dateFrom` and `@dateTo`.  That doesn't belong there.  Why was it there again?

Answer (score 1):

TRY this

```
    SET @dateFrom = ''
    SET @dateTo = ''

    SELECT [tNumber], [createdDate], [Total], [pfAmount] FROM [webtable]
    WHERE [tNumber] LIKE '%' 
    AND CASE 
            WHEN (@dateFrom = '' OR @dateTo = '') THEN ([createdDate] LIKE '%')
        ELSE  ([createdDate] BETWEEN @dateFrom and @dateTo)
        END
```

Comment: thanks for your solution! it still shows no results when the parameters are empty, any idea?

Comment: Thanks again for the update, however it says syntax error near '([createdDate] LIKE'

Comment: You might have missed a bracket or something.. What syntax error it says ?

Comment: The query i have pasted has no syantax errors. Where are you executing this ? on SQL management studio. I tried there it works fine for me. Try to copying freshly or try executing only this query separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SET @dateFrom = ''
SET @dateTo = ''
IF(@dateFrom = '' AND @dateTo='')
BEGIN
SELECT [tNumber], [createdDate], [Total], [pfAmount] FROM [webtable]
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT [tNumber], [createdDate], [Total], [pfAmount] FROM [webtable]
WHERE [tNumber] LIKE '%' 
AND [createdDate] > convert(DATE,@dateFrom) 
AND [createdDate] < COnvert(Date,@dateTo)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare @fdate datetime
 declare @tdate datetime
 set @fdate=''--'2013-10-10'
 set @tdate=''--'2013-10-10'
 select * from yourTable where (datefield>@fdate or @fdate='') and (datefield<@tdate or @tdate='')
```

try this..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [tNumber], [createdDate], [Total], [pfAmount] FROM [webtable]
WHERE [tNumber] LIKE '%' 
AND (@dateFrom = '' OR [createdDate] > @dateFrom+'%')
AND (@dateTo = '' OR [createdDate] < @dateTo+'%')
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of the `[tNumber] LIKE '%' `, unless you want to force a table scan...  Was it returning results too quickly?

Comment: [tNumber] is not null is probably more efficient

Comment: @dav1dsm1th i forgot to include the tbnumber search parameter in the query, e.g. [tNumber] LIKE `@searchTNumber+'%'`, that lets it return all records if null

Answer (score 0):

To show the Records with dates are null you can use the below query like this

```
select * from [webtable] where ID not in (Select ID from [webtable] where  [createdDate] > COnvert(Date, ''))
```